Finding the maximum value of $f(x)= \frac{x^4 - x^2}{x^6 + 2x^3 - 1} ; x>1$.
Let $$f(x)= \frac{x^4 - x^2}{x^6 + 2x^3 - 1} ; x>1.$$

What is the best method to find the maximum value of $f(x)$?

I tried dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^3$ to simplify the expression but it was still very cumbersome calculation. Is there a better way to do it?

Hi. Please format your equations accordingly

A standard approach is to use derivative tests from Calculus. Interestingly, the maximum here seems to occur when x is the golden ratio.

could you kindly share your calculations?

This margin is too narrow to contain it. Find the derivative and then set it to zero to solve.

If we make the change of variable $u = x - 1/x$, one gets that
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{4} - x^{2}}{x^{6} + 2x^{3} - 1} & = \frac{x - 1/x}{x^{3} - 1/x^{3} + 2} = \frac{u}{u(u^{2} + 3) + 2} = \frac{u}{u^{3} + 3u + 2}
\end{align*}
Consequently, it can be concluded that
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{u}{u^{3} + 3u + 2}\right)' & = \frac{(u^{3} + 3u + 2) - u(3u^{2} + 3)}{(u^{3} + 3u + 2)^{2}} = \frac{2 - 2u^{3}}{(u^{3} + 3u + 2)^{2}} = 0 \Rightarrow u = 1
\end{align*}
whence we arrive at the equation
\begin{align*}
x - \frac{1}{x} = 1 & \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} - x - 1 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align*}
Given that $x > 1$, the proposed function attains its maximum at $x = \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.
Hopefully this helps!

For every $x>1$, $$f'(x)=\frac{-2x(x^6+x^5-x+1)}{(x^6+2x^3-1)^2}(x^2-x-1)$$
is negative iff $x^2-x-1>0$, i.e. $x>\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$. The maximum value of $f$ is therefore
$$f(\varphi)=\frac16.$$
Notes:

The factor $x^2-x-1$ of the numerator of $f'(x)$ was guessed by recognizing, on a plot of $f$, that it seemed to attain its maximum at $\varphi$.
We did not need to factor $x^6+x^5-x+1$: it is obviously positive for every $x>1$.


$$f(x)= \frac{x^4 - x^2}{x^6 + 2x^3 - 1}$$
Computing the first derivative and factoring
$$f'(x)=-\frac{2 \left(x^9-2 x^7-x^6-x^4+2 x^3-x\right)}{\left(x^6+2
   x^3-1\right)^2}$$
Factoring it
$$f'(x)=-\frac{2 x \left(x^2+1\right) \left(x^2-x-1\right)
   \left(x^4+x^3-x^2-x+1\right)}{\left(x^6+2 x^3-1\right)^2}$$
The quartic term does not show any real solution (check the discriminants).
So $\cdots\cdots$ ?

got it, every term in the numerator of f'(x) is always positive except for the quadratic, so we can equate it to 0, get the roots, then apply the sign scheme to find the value of x for which the function is maximum.

@ThrisshaArcot. This is perfectly true.

Right, mine was more detailed, and the argument for the sign of $f'$ was way simpler.

Your disagreement (whatever the reason) is not a problem. Actually, I didn't intend to argue about your answer. I was only advertising for mine for future readers.

Let $u := x - 1/x > 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
 f &= \frac{x - 1/x}{x^3 + 2 - 1/x^3}\\
 &= \frac{x - 1/x}{(x - 1/x)^3 + 3(x - 1/x) + 2}\\
 &= \frac{u}{u^3 + 3u + 2}\\
 &= \frac{1}{u^2 + 3 + 2/u}\\
 &= \frac{1}{(u^2 + 1/u + 1/u) + 3}\\
 &\le \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{u^2 \cdot 1/u\cdot 1/u} + 3}\\
 &= \frac{1}{6}.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, when $x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, we have $f = \frac16$. Thus, the maximum of $f$ is $1/6$.
